# Unable to understand handling events in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, events, event-handling

I am practicing react since past two days and when i started 'Handling events' section, i was unable to understand the following piece of code. Can anybody help me with this ?

[This is the image of the code that i am trying to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwDsP.png)

Comment: Which part of code are you having trouble with, please be specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the binding of react method to the event callback, so we can access the `this` of the react component class inside the event callback method.
There are three ways to bind your method in react.

1. **In constructor**.
   One of the best way to bind your functions because constructor will be called only once in the whole react component life cycle.

   ```
   class Test {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick(e) {
     // Do whatever you want to here
    }
   }
   ```
2. **Use arrow functions**. Simple but not recommended because it'll bind and initialize the method for every call of render function, which will reduce the performance.

   ```
   <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}/>
   ```
3. **Define arrow function as class property**.

   ```
   class Test {
    handleClick = (e) => {
     // Do whatever you want to here
    }
    render() {
     return(
      ...
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}/>
     )
    }
   }
   ```

   For better performance you can use any method from 1 and 3 but try to avoid method 2.

Comment: Thank you! I have one last doubt. when do we actually use 'this' and why do we have to ? if you could help me with an example, it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

By default there are a number of [HTML DOM events](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) and for those events there is a [Synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) in React which wraps the native event. Refer the official documentation to get an in-depth understanding of those two types of events.

In the above code when the user **click** on the button, the event which corresponds to click action (i.e. On Click event) will be fired and React will wrap the native event with a syntactic event and invoke the respective event handler function. In the above code, that function is **handleClick()**. Within that function you can execute your logic which corresponds to the user click action on the button.

Note that by default, the syntactic event will be passed as the first argument to the **handleClick()** function. Hence, you can write it as below.

```
handleClick(event) {
    console.log(event)
    // your logic
}
```

There is a lot of [supported events in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events) which you can use to capture user actions and modify the behavior of your application accordingly.